# Usar el retorno de una función desde otra clase

Tags: java

Sucede lo siguiente, tengo 2 clases una se llama ventana_login y la otra login.
en la clase ventana_login el usuario inicia sesión con usuario y contraseña.
en la clase login el se reciben los valores de usuario y contraseña para verificarlos contra la BBDD.

mi clase login que verifica contra la BBDD el usuario y la contraseña. Tiene un return que necesito llamar desde mi clase ventana_login para igualarlo a una variable de tipo global y publica que existe en esta clase.

clase login

```
public class login extends connect{


public String validarusuario(String DBUsuario, String DBcontrasena){
    connect nc = new connect();
    Connection x = nc.conectar();
    Gestor ges = new Gestor();
    String variabletipo = null;

    try {

        Statement ss = x.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ss.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM persona WHERE pk_ci='"+DBUsuario+"' AND contrasena='"+DBcontrasena+"'");


        while(rs.next()) {

            variabletipo = rs.getString("tipo");

            ges.run();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return variabletipo;

}
```

}

y a continuación el fragmento de mi clase ventana_login que es el boton ingresar y necesito que dentro del evento luego de validar que el usuario y contraseña son correctos iguale mi variable global al retorno de la clase login.

la variable global que es **public String rol;** y que la creo antes del main de ventana login.

codigo ventana_login

```
 JButton btnIngresar = new JButton("Ingresar");
btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        log_login v= new log_login();
        v.validausuario(txtUsuario.getText(),textContrasena.getText());
        if (v != null) {

            //AQUI Necesito que ROL = variabletipo (que es el return de la funcion public class login
            frame.dispose();

        }
    }
});
btnIngresar.setFocusPainted(false);
btnIngresar.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        btnIngresar.setBackground(new Color(244, 133, 45));
    }
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        btnIngresar.setBackground(null);
    }
});
btnIngresar.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("X");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que veo aca, va mas alla del lenguaje que estas usando. Es un error de conceptos y de desconocimiento de como funciona una funcion.

No importa donde este ubicada una función. Si la misma tiene un valor de retorno, el mismo se puede tomar e igualar a una variable desde donde hiciste la llamada.

Las funciones tiene parametros de entrada (los que van entre parentesis) y parametros de salida (lo que pones antes del nombre de la función). Veamos como define Java a una función (o metodo, el nombre se usa indistintamente) ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)).

La firma de un método es la siguiente, en este orden:

1. Un modificador de entorno, como public o private
2. El tipo de retorno del método, o `VOID` si no retorna nada
3. El nombre del método.
4. La lista de parametros que recibira el método, separado por comas. Cada parametro va precedido por su tipo, y esta lista esta encerrada entre parentesis
5. La lista de excepciones que lanzara este método.
6. El cuerpo del método, encerrado entre llaves {}

Ahora bien, como vimos todo eso forma parte del método al cual estamos llamando. Como vemos ahi, en el punto 2, hay algo que retorna. Entonces como se toma el retorno de un método?

Para obtenerlo, basta con igualar la función a una variable.

Como tu metodo validar usuario devuelve un string, lo unico que necesitamos es tomar ese string en la llamada de la siguiente forma:

```
string Retorno = v.validausuario(txtUsuario.getText(),textContrasena.getText());
```

Y en Retorno, nos va a quedar lo que esa función devolvio.

Hay que tener en cuenta que no importa donde este la función, si la podemos llamar y devuelve algo, entonces lo podemos obtener y usar.

Comment: excelente, sirvió. Mi problema fue que no sabia que la variable igualada de esa manera iba a devolver el retorno. Ya que eso mismo utilizo para enviar los valores a la función validar usuario en login. tendre que crear una funcion aparte para que me devuelva solo el retorno sin hacer la validación 2 veces.